# unable to import pygame

Tags: macos, pygame, importerror

I have installed pygames on my mac, using the installer in the following package found on the pygame.org site: pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg.

I have installed python with the Python 2.7.2 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer found on python.org, and ran `easy_install pyobjc` so that I now have pyobjc 2.2 installed.

But when I try the to import pygame in the repl, I get this:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit this is a guess, but could this be a 32 vs. 64 bit issue?

If I do:

```
file /usr/bin/python
```

I get:

```
python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
python (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
python (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
```

Wondering what you see on your add-in file?

For example, if it's 32 bit, then run Python that mode:

```
arch -i386 /usr/bin/python
```

If that's not exactly it, at least this will hopefully get you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, this is almost certainly a 32 bit vs. 64 bit issue.  Are you sure you installed the correct PyGame for your system?

Answer (score 3):

This was a 32 bit vs 64 bit issue for me. I followed the directions listed here: http://web.mit.edu/6.090/www/pygame.html and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I am also unable to import pygame, but it just say 'ImportError: No module named pygame'. Could that also be 32b vs 64b issue?
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit); Ubuntu 14.04
I used 'sudo apt-get install python-pygame', and that appeared to work. I tried clicking your link now, but it is dead.